# 一度スキップした項目に対してレビューを行うには？

Tags: サポート

最初にレビューキューで表示されてレビューしたときには、確証が持てずに「スキップ」したのですが、後々に再考した結果、確証が持てるようになったレビュー項目があるとします。

これは、再びレビューできますか？その場合、どのようにこの項目にアクセスできますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いくつか分かったことがあるので共有です。

1. 「スキップ」した項目をレビューし直すことは可能です。どうにかしてそのレビューにアクセスできればいいです。
2. 自分のレビュー一覧(スキップを含む)の画面から、レビュー画面にアクセスすることができます。各種のレビュー画面, 「履歴」タブ, したの方にスクロールした結果出てくる「レビュー履歴」です。この画面で、レビュー結果がリンクになっているので、それをクリックするとレビュー画面に飛びます。